# wp job manager custom filter

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using "wp job manager" and trying to filter/search by a custom field that I have added to the jobs on submission. 
   The plugin author offers a tutorial for adding a dropdown menu to filter an added 'salary' field, and I would like to modify this tutorial to use a text box instead of a dropdown.

The tutorial is located here: https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-adding-a-salary-field-for-jobs/

Assuming the data is correctly submitted with the job (in my case it is), the following code allows you to filter the jobs with a dropdown menu, selecting between price ranges.

```
    add_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', 'filter_by_salary_field' );
function filter_by_salary_field() {
    ?>
    <div class="search_categories">
        <label for="search_categories"><?php _e( 'Salary', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
        <select name="filter_by_salary" class="job-manager-filter">
            <option value=""><?php _e( 'Any Salary', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
            <option value="upto20"><?php _e( 'Up to $20,000', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
            <option value="20000-40000"><?php _e( '$20,000 to $40,000', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
            <option value="40000-60000"><?php _e( '$40,000 to $60,000', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
            <option value="over60"><?php _e( '$60,000+', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php
}
/**
 * This code gets your posted field and modifies the job search query
 */
add_filter( 'job_manager_get_listings', 'filter_by_salary_field_query_args', 10, 2 );
function filter_by_salary_field_query_args( $query_args, $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['form_data'] ) ) {
        parse_str( $_POST['form_data'], $form_data );
        // If this is set, we are filtering by salary
        if ( ! empty( $form_data['filter_by_salary'] ) ) {
            $selected_range = sanitize_text_field( $form_data['filter_by_salary'] );
            switch ( $selected_range ) {
                case 'upto20' :
                    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                        'key'     => '_job_salary',
                        'value'   => '20000',
                        'compare' => '<',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
                    );
                break;
                case 'over60' :
                    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                        'key'     => '_job_salary',
                        'value'   => '60000',
                        'compare' => '>=',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
                    );
                break;
                default :
                    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                        'key'     => '_job_salary',
                        'value'   => array_map( 'absint', explode( '-', $selected_range ) ),
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
                    );
                break;
            }
            // This will show the 'reset' link
            add_filter( 'job_manager_get_listings_custom_filter', '__return_true' );
        }
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

What I need to do, is change the dropdown menu to a textbox, and if I search "20000", to have only jobs with a saved 'salary' of 20000 to show. 
(In the end this won't be a salary field, but the tutorial seemed like a good base to start from)

I have made some attempts, but have failed to make this work properly. 
By changing the input to a textbox, and deleting the options, I have a limited search capability eg. I can search for "over60" and the jobs with a value of 60000 or over are shown, but searching for 60000 (or any random selection of letters and numbers) brings up all the jobs without filtering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have already added a salary field per the WP Job Manager documentation, this code should give you what you are looking for:

```
add_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', 'filter_by_salary_field' );
function filter_by_salary_field() {
    ?>
    <div class="search_categories">
        <label for="search_categories"><?php _e( 'Search Salary Amounts', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="job-manager-filter" name="filter_by_salary" placeholder="Search Salary Amounts">
    </div>
    <?php
}
/**
 * This code gets your posted field and modifies the job search query
 */
add_filter( 'job_manager_get_listings', 'filter_by_salary_field_query_args', 10, 2 );
function filter_by_salary_field_query_args( $query_args, $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['form_data'] ) ) {
        parse_str( $_POST['form_data'], $form_data );
        // If this is set, we are filtering by salary
        if ( ! empty( $form_data['filter_by_salary'] ) ) {
            $salary = sanitize_text_field( $form_data['filter_by_salary'] );
            $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => '_job_salary',
                'value'   =>  $salary,
                'compare' => '=',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
            );

            // This will show the 'reset' link
            add_filter( 'job_manager_get_listings_custom_filter', '__return_true' );
        }
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

It will do as you requested and only return results that match exactly how they were input when the job was submitted.  Meaning if you submit a job with a number in the salary field of "55,000" you will need the comma to find that job listing on the job search page.  if a user searches for a salary of "55000" no results would be returned in that case however a result would return if they searched for "55,000"

If you want to account for various currency characters (i.e. dollar symbols, commas, and trailing cents) you might want to look into using regular expressions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

You mentioned that you will want to use it for something other than salaries, so there will need to be further modification if you want to use it for searching for content other than numbers.  Among other possible changes, one line you will probably want to remove all together is:

```
'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
```

**Note:**  When you pass these items through the 'job_manger_get_listings' filter, you are sending this data into a function that utilizes WP_Query.  When you are passing back $query_args['meta_query']  in your code, you are more specifically using the WP_Meta_Query part of WP_Query.  Knowing that might help make sense of modifying the above code.  See documentation here for further reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer, this has really helped me a lot. I am using this to search min and max dates, so I changed filter names, 'type'    => 'date' and changed compare to <= and >=. Using a jquery datepicker this filters perfectly. Unfortunatly I dont have enough feedback to upvote you.

Comment: Glad it helped!  I was searching for a question of my own and stumbled across your question... Since I recently had to do the same thing I figured I'd pass it along. Hopefully it will help someone else as well.

Comment: @ahurleb I want same solution for state n city. So please help me. urgently

Comment: @Dnyan - WP Job Manager already has the option to search by location. If you want to limit the functionality to only specific states, use the Predefined Regions (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager-locations/) add-on and create the City, State combo in the "Add Regions" section. There's an option in the settings page to replace the location field with a drop down list of the regions you create.

Comment: @ahurleb That plugin give predefined region but i want to populate dropdown on selection of state. but i am not able to filter out result. I have used above solution but results are not filtered so please help. From above code I have removed the type & compare attribute. Instead of these which attribute is suitable for filtering result. also tell me how to populate state on select of city.

Comment: Hi @ahurleb , i'm having problems with my filter, could you pls review it, im sure i'm missing something : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161107/custom-taxonomy-not-working-in-wp-job-manager

Comment: Hi, i am having some problems with custom field filter, can any one please help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459779/wp-job-manager-custom-filter-on-date